# Image acquiring hardware for taking photos of a wide surface, from a close distance

Tags: optics, optical-materials

I am looking for the right image acquiring hardware to enable me to take photos of a wide 44cm X 23cm 3D surface (imaging a land with mountains) from a distance between 10cm to 25cm. 
The depth of the surface can reach up to 10 cm.

The goal is also to be able to see each part of the surface from a frontal angle (from 0 angle).

Any ideas?

I thought about CIS but I am not sure about its ability to deal with the depth and a distance higher than 10cm.
Also, about a stereo camera module, but it added a photo stitching complexity.

Thanks

Comment: This isn't really on-topic here. Try photography SE

Comment: Is CIS the same as a "fish-eye" lens?